# Storing global state in react-native/react-navigation app?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I have a react native/react navigation app with two screens. Before I implemented react-navigation I had a overarching App component that made an api call and passed the returned object to both screens as props. Now that I've implemented react-navigation, I'm not sure where to make the api call in order manage the state effectively and pass down the object correctly to both screens. Redux might be an option, but it doesn't seem write to make an api call in a sub component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With react-navigation you can pass data down through screen props...

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('AnotherScreen', {User: {name: 'john doe', age: 27}}})
```

Then you can access these props...

```
this.props.navigation.state.params.User
```

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-prop.html

https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/760

https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/728

[React Navigation pass props in TabNavigator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46264767/react-navigation-pass-props-in-tabnavigator)

Comment: Hi Gavin, I have tabbed navigation, similar to the minimal example demonstrated here https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/tab-based-navigation.html. I haven't been able to figure out how to pass through parameters with this set up.

Comment: This example is just a demonstration, instead of declaring jsx and your 'settings' component in your navigation file you can create them just like any other react component and import them. Then use them as a screen.

Comment: Ive updated my OP to reflect numerous solutions to your problem with tabnavigator.