# Pass data between Multiple StackNavigator React Navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

```
const CategoriesStack = StackNavigator({
  Category: {
    screen: CategoryScreen,
    navigationOptions: () => ({
      tabBarVisible: true,
      header: null
    }),
  },
  Product: {
    screen: ProductScreen,
    navigationOptions: () => ({
      tabBarVisible: false
    }),
  }
},
{
  initialRouteName: 'Category',
  navigationOptions: {
    headerTitleStyle: {
      fontWeight: 'normal',
    }
  }
});
```

...

```
const HomeStack = StackNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: HomeScreen,
    navigationOptions: () => ({
      tabBarVisible: true,
      header: null
    }),
  },
  Search: {
    screen: SearchScreen,
    navigationOptions: () => ({
      tabBarVisible: false,
      header : null
    }),
  }
}, 
{
  initialRouteName: 'Home',
  navigationOptions: {
    headerTitleStyle: {
      fontWeight: 'normal',
    }
  }
});
```

SO I have two Stack navigators bind in a Tab Navigator. From HomeStack -> HomeScreen I need to pass data to CategoriesStack -> initial route name. I can't find a way to do this.

I didn't know how to get that right.

[image: Please refer]

Comment: Is this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46264767/react-navigation-pass-props-in-tabnavigator/46264894#46264894) answering you needs?

Comment: @cowCrazy the above answer is sharing a data to tab navigator from main navigation screen so what I need is I am in Home stack now I need to share a data to Map stack both are separate StackNavigator which consist of many screen

Comment: @AshokkumarAdichill did you find any solution to this?

Comment: @amansoni211 no but there is a way of doing is using AsynsStore to store the value and use willFocus subscription for which screen I needed the data and get it from AsyncStore. So every time the screen will show it will get the lastly stored value from Async.